# C++: Are local automatic variables initialized or not? Stroustrup example

Tags: c++, c++11

The following example is from Stroustrup C++ 4th Ed. Page 519.  It was my understanding from K&R C and earlier in the Stroustrup book that local automatic variables of primitive types **are undefined or not known to be initialized**.  Static variables of primitive types or automatic variables of a class with a default constructor are initialized.

That would mean `int b` should be undefined and not known to be initialized.  Yet, Stroustrup adds the following code comment saying `b = 0`.  Is this Errata? Or perhaps some behavior of calling with the default constructor?

Thank you

```
struct S { 
   string a;
   int b;
};

void f(void) {
   S s0 {}; // default construction: {"",0}
   // ...
}
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization

Comment: takes me to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization.  I might be better off reading the standard?

Comment: The `{};` is an initializer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easy. You can leave the built-in type variables uninitialized or you can ask the compiler to zero-initialize them.

```
S s1;   // string is default initialized, int is left uninitialized
S s2{}; // All fields are initialized.
```

Notice the `{}`. That (in this case) asks the compiler to initialize all fields.

Comment: In both cases the default constructor S() is invoked.

Comment: @notaorb No, it's a bit more complicated. You don't have a user-defined constructor, so it works the way I explained in the answer.

Comment: @notaorb More precisely, [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) rules apply.

Comment: Thanks, I added a user defined constructor to observe above behavior.  `S s1` comment agrees with what I read earlier in Stroustrup, interested if you have a source for `S s2{}` case he is using?

Comment: @notaorb if you add a user-defined constructor, both examples will call it. Whether or not fields are initialized then depends on if the constructor initializes them.

Comment: @notaorb from that cppreference link I shared: *"If the number of initializer clauses is less than the number of members and bases (since C++17) or initializer list is completely empty, the remaining members and bases (since C++17) are initialized by their default member initializers,"*

Comment: Ok, aggregate list initialization makes sense.  It only works without a user defined constructor per his example.  `S s2{}` must initialize each item in the aggregate to a default value.  `int` must have a default value of 0.

Comment: *"It's easy."*. Unfortunately not, C++ has lot of initialization ways/types, corner cases.

Comment: @Jarod42 you rarely need to know those corner-cases. This specific case isn't particularly hard to understand intuitively.

Answer (score 4):

In this line:

```
S s0 {};
```

the *syntax* that is used is [*value-initialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization), in particular

> 4. when a named variable (automatic, static, or thread-local) is declared with the initializer consisting of a pair of braces.

In this case, the effect of value-initialization is that the object `s0` is [*zero-initialized*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization).

In this particular case, the *effect* is:

> If T is an non-union class type, all base classes and non-static data members are zero-initialized, and all padding is initialized to zero bits. The constructors, if any, are ignored.

which implies that the `int` member `b` is zero-initialized to the value `0`.

Answer (score 1):

> Are local automatic variables initialized or not?

It depends on the initialisation syntax that is used, the type of the variable, as well as the storage class.

> That would mean int b should be undefined

No, because the example uses value initialisation, and the class in question is an aggregate.